# Why is my new table not showing in Oracle Enterprise Manager?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-enterprise-manager

I created a new table with SQL Developer like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE "MYCHEMA"."NEWTABLE" 
  ( "ID" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
     CONSTRAINT "NEWTABLE_1" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
     USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
     STORAGE(INITIAL 458752 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
     PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
     CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
     TABLESPACE "MYCHEMA"  ENABLE
 ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 524288 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
  CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 TABLESPACE "MYCHEMA";
```

But it's not showing in Oracle Enterprise Manager when I search on TABLE objects for that schema, only existing tables appear.

In SQL Developer though, I can see all of them (including the new ones I just created) and perform queries.

Is there a restart required or something? (Which I can't do before the end of the day)

Comment: try after refreshing table objects.

Comment: Without trying to be funny or silly: how do I refresh table objects?

Comment: If you enclosed the tablename within quotes, it might be at the end. Did you check at the end of the list?

Comment: Yes, I checked the whole list (still no new tables visible). But I suppose it has something to do with "table objects". Are these generated automatically when executing a CREATE table statement?

Comment: @JosephB: double quotes are a standard way to quote object names, they are _not_ stored in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Oracle Enterprise Manager was pointing to the wrong database. I created the new tables on the backup server, but our webbased interface always points to the production database, no matter the URL.